# Writing to storage from handler

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-storm

I'm trying to write the stream of my array that is coming from Bluetooth module and read from (HandleRead), to the internal storage directly. Is that possible in the first place?
Note that I am reading 100 samples per second. That means the file will fill up quickly. I am not familiar with storage, and my code isn't executed as I expected.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File Dir = new File (Root.getAbsolutePath()+"/myAppFile");
    File file = new File(Dir,"Message.txt"); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        String state;
        state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            if (!Dir.exists()){
                Dir.mkdir();
            }
        }

        private void handleRead(Message msg) {
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;    
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf);
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length);
            buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
            buffer.clear();

            final String[] strNumbers = readMessage.split("\n");

            for (int j = 1; j <= strNumbers.length - 2; j++) {
                pressure = Integer.parseInt(readMessage2);
                MyFinalPressure = (float) (9.677 +0.831 * pressure);
                // trying to store directly to internal sotrage
                activity.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(activity.file);
                            fileOutputStream.write((int) MyFinalPressure);
                            fileOutputStream.close();

                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"Message saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For debugging your Toast might want to be a Logcat log instead. That way you get a better sense for what is happening. Toasts are hard to test with and keep track of. (only good for a quick visual test, at least for debugging) Also does the toast(or logs in future edit) ever appear?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not [setting the FileOutputStream to 'append'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) (you need to add 'true' as 2nd parameter in constructor.)

This would write over the file from the file-start every time

---

also your 'setOnClickListener' is INSIDE your loop. This doesn't do anything for you as far as I can tell.

I recommend always setting up UI elements in a `private void setupUI() {...}` method that onCreate calls. The `public void onClick(View v) {buttonForSavingPresssed()}` where `buttonForSavingPressed(){...}` is the 'logic' of your onClick() method.

This will help you clean up the class and not have stray onClickListener assignments, etc.

My guess is that either your multiple assignments is very inefficient, since clickListeners aren't cheap, or... the clickListener might not even work at all because of a timing issue (if your loop is long running and you press the button and the listener has already been swapped for a new one)

I've cleaned up your code some, There are some suggestions and some log statements that should help you figure out what is going on.

```
// this is inside your onCreate()

...
activity.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                              
    @Override                                                                                              
    public void onClick(View v) { buttonPressed();} 
});                                                                   

... 

// Here is where you would put your logic when the button is presssed
public void buttonPressed(){
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"Button Pressed ",   
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
}

// you should make 'helper' functions that consolidate separate pieces of logic like this, 
// that way you can more easily track what is happening in each method. 
// Plus it helps keep each method shorter for ease of understanding, etc.
public void writeToFile(float finalPressure){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG // where LOG_TAG is the String name of this class
          "writeToFile(float) called." );
    try{  
        // true here for 'append'                      
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new 
            FileOutputStream(activity.file, true);  
        fileOutputStream.write((int) finalPressure);                                                 
        fileOutputStream.close();  
     }catch (FileNotFoundException e){                                                                  
         e.printStackTrace();                                                                           
     } catch (IOException e) {                                                                          
         e.printStackTrace();                                                                           
     }    
}

// now back to your handleRead, is this method called async wenever
// a message is read? Then wouldn't this be called a lot? I'm lost as to why 
// you had the button in here at all.
private void handleRead(Message msg) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG // where LOG_TAG is the String name of this class
          "handleRead(Message) called." );
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;    
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    buffer.clear();


    final String[] strNumbers = readMessage.split("\n");

    Log.d(LOG_TAG // where LOG_TAG is the String name of this class
          "strNumbers length: " + strNumbers.length );

    for (int j = 1; j <= strNumbers.length - 2; j++) {
         pressure = Integer.parseInt(readMessage2);
         MyFinalPressure = (float) (9.677 +0.831 * pressure);
         // trying to store directly to internal sotrage                                                                                                        
         writeToFile(MyFinalPressure);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, inside (Red handle() method ) is what am really reading from the Bluetooth module. it is long loop process of the array that keeps pushing that array to my listView adapter, but I didn't add that code.  However. your code was useful. Thanks a lot. I was trying to let the user regulate on writing and closing the file of being written. that is why I have put a button on Click. In your case, it isn't useable. now am wondering, can I make toggle button a user can start writing and stop writing? I have modified the code a little bit to have **fileOutputStream.flush();**  Thanks

Comment: You should be able to have a class variable that works as flag, that the loop checks each time, just set that flag to false in buttonPressed() if that is what you want.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in ToggleButton. I have surrounded my method **writeToFile(MyFinalPressure)** with isChecked, (For toggleButton) then do that method, if it isn't not, then set the global boolean to false. But it is not working.